# Plugin "processing" does not work - not possible to enable - QGIS 3.4.3 Madeira - Windows 10 Pro

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

The "Spatial data processing framework for QGIS" does not work anymore.

Also known as "processing".... this tool can not be uninstalled...

and it is disabled.

QGIS 3.4.3 Madeira - Windows 10 Pro

[image]

When i try to enable it, QGIS crashes...

I tried to uninstall QGIS and also cleaned the registry and install QGIS again, but the same happens again...it seems that QGIS saves all the adjustments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems that QGIS saves all the adjustments.

You need to remove the `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\QGIS` (hidden) folder too, for a clean install.

Also, you can first try to heal the situation by uninstalling *Invalid* (*Ungültig*) plugins and upgrading  the *Upgradeable* (*Aktualisebar*) ones.

Comment: You need to remove the C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\QGIS (hidden) folder too, for a clean install.  Thank you very much, that's it!

Comment: @Vik, you are welcome. Please, edit the body of the question by adding information about the version of QGIS and the operating system, so that subsequent searches are more effective for those who have a similar problem.

Comment: Sure! No Problem

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problems with the standalone installer(s) and SAGA/GRASS/GDAL not working with certain plugins (CSMapMaker) specifically.  I tried on two different Windows 10 machines and even went back to ltr 2.18 release with same results.

After two days of installing re-installing and thinking it was something to do with my data, I re-installed one last time with the OSGeo4W network installer and now everything works fine.

Why do the standalone drivers get released if they break GRASS and SAGA? Why does the network installer work? Or is there a correct way to install with the standalone that doesn't break SAGA/GRASS? If there is it would be helpful to describe it here...