# QGIS keeps closing when trying to reenable the Processing Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, windows

Refers to:
QGIS version 3.22.2
Windows 10

I was doing first steps in the processing script environment and added testwise the code line

`qgs = QgsApplication([], False)`

to the processing script. After I clicked 'run', QGIS crashed and when I now open it, the toolbox is missing. I read, that I seem to have disabled the Processing Plugin. I confirmed it by looking into the Plugin Menu, and yes, the Plugin is not enabled anymore (the box left to the Processing is empty)
[image: Processing Plugin is not enabled]
However, when I try to re-enable the Processing Plugin via the Plugin-menu, QGIS is shutting down again without that it is enabling the Plugin.

What happened here, and how can I re-enable the Processing Plugin again?

Comment: which version? operating system? with a clean profile?

Comment: It is QGIS 3.22.2 with Windows 10. What is a clean profile? Do you refer to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307570/plugin-processing-does-not-work-not-possible-to-enable-qgis-3-4-3-madeira?rq=1 ? 
I didn't do a reinstall yet and so didn't clean the mentioned profile folder, instead I thought there may be a way to re-enable the Plugin in the current profile (I'm working on a work PC where I don't have admin rights to install QGIS on my own).

Comment: please [edit] your question - before you delete your existing profile, just try with a clean one.

Comment: What processing script?

Comment: @IanTurton To create a new profile did work. Thank you! So now I have a working processing plugin. I gave the answer to this question, or maybe better, the practical solution, below.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for this problem was to create a new, clean user profile, as decribed in here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles.

This will create a completely new profile with a working processing plugin. However, configurations from your old user will be lost, e.g. you will have to newly define you xyz-tiles or your language settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with a new User-Profile.

You can create it with: 'Settings' -> 'User Profile' -> 'New Profile...'

You will get a new and clean Profile without any installed 3-party-Plugins!

Comment: Oh, didn't see you answer! Sorry!